# Ignore unused argument when calling a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to ignore both the argument and the output linked to it by using '_':

```py
data_scaled, _, scaler = scaling(sequence_arr,*_)
```

The function is:

```py
def scaling(x, y):
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1])
    y = y.reshape(y.shape[0], y.shape[1])
    scale = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    scale = scale.fit(x)
    x_scaled = scale.transform(x)
    y_scaled = scale.transform(y)
    return x_scaled, y_scaled, scale
```

I get the error:

```py
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

Comment: if the function takes 2 arguments, you should provide 2 arguments.

Comment: You cannot ignore an argument of a function

Comment: you can, but it have to have default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make `y` optional and go from there.

```py
def scaling(x, y=None):
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1])
    scale = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    scale = scale.fit(x)
    x_scaled = scale.transform(x)
    if y is not None:
        y = y.reshape(y.shape[0], y.shape[1])
        y_scaled = scale.transform(y)
    else:
        y_scaled = None
    return x_scaled, y_scaled, scale
```

You can then call it like

```py
data_scaled, _, scaler = scaling(sequence_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to unpack `_` here:

```
data_scaled, _, scaler = scaling(sequence_arr,*_)
```

Unpacking only works on existing.

You can only use `_` for assignment - for ignoring the value idiomatically.

For ignoring extra arguments to `scaling`, you need to change the function itself.

```
def scaling(x, y, *args, **kwargs):
```

The idiomatic pythion function definition, takes any extra positional arguments into `args` & keyword arguments into `kwargs`

Answer (score 0):

The error is given by the use of `*_` in the call because the `_` variable isn't defined. The `_` in the assignment is OK because the variable gets created.

In general you can't "ignore" an argument which is expected by the function, unless it has a default value. You should at least pass something like `None`:

```
#                                x =           y =
data_scaled, _, scaler = scaling(sequence_arr, None)
```

However in your case this will raise an error as `reshape` is called on the `None` object.